# how to create multivariate function handle in matlab in this case?

Tags: function, matlab

I would like to create a multivariate functional handle which the number of variables is changeable according to the input.

First, create `n` symbolic variables, and note that `n` can be changed according to your input.

```
n=3;
syms theta [1 n];
```

Now I create a function `g`. Via For loop, create the summation of `g` on all `theta`. As seen in the code, `f` is a symbolic expression.

```
g = @(x)(x^2);
f = 0;
for i = 1:n
    f = f + g(sym(sprintfc('theta%d',i)))
end
```

Now I want to create a functional handle `F` according to `f`.

One potential way to do this `F = @(theta1,theta2,theta3)(f)`. However, since `n` is user-specified, changeable variable, this approach is not doable.

Could someone give my hint? Many thanks!

Comment: use arrays? If that is not what wors for you, can you simplyfy this example? there is an extreme amount of superfluous information that makes it harder what you mean with your example. Also, there is no Latex support, so don't use it.

Comment: @AnderBiguri Thank you for your suggestion. I just re-write my question.

Comment: What is wrong with the use of arrays? You can have `F = @(theta)disp(length(theta))`, or anything more complex that rely `theta` being an array.

Comment: @AnderBiguri If I wrote `F = @(theta)f` and then `F([1,1,1]` will give me `ans =theta1^2 + theta2^2 + theta3^2`. But the correct output should be `3`.

Comment: But that has nothing to do with the input being an array, but with a bad definition of `f`. Its not clear to me how the `f` in your example code relates to an anonymous function.  an you show your attempt to replace the code that you gave as an example?

Comment: @AnderBiguri `f` is `theta1^2 + theta2^2 + theta3^2` in my code.

Comment: and why the loop? I mean, this code is basically `f=sum(g(theta))`, right? (as long as you make `g` accept arrays (`g = @(x)(x.^2);`). This works for any `n`

Comment: @AnderBiguri This is a simplified example code, where the summation `g(theta1)+g(theta2)+g(theta3)` can be written in the matrix form: `f = @(x)(x.^2)`, where `x` is the vector of `theta`. However in the real case, I cannot write `sum(g(theta))` as matrix form (I have the question related to it here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4568232/how-to-convert-this-formula-into-matrix-form)

Comment: You will need to show an minimal example of the real problem then.... I still don't know if this is a hard or a trivial problem

Comment: The minimal example can be obtain via changing `g=@(x)(x^2);` to `g=@(x)( ( cos(x) +(cos(3*x))/9+(cos(5*x))/25+(cos(7*x))/49+(cos(9*x))/81 )`.

Comment: I see no code difference between your two functions. Given you replace the `*` by `.*`, you should be able to use `sum(g(theta))` in the same way

Comment: I don't understand, how can I obtain `f(theta1)+f(theta2)+f(theta3)` through `sum(g(theta))`? `theta` is a vector, i.e. `[theta1,theta2,theta3]`.

Comment: What do you mean "I don't understand"? that is what the code does. `theta=[theta1,theta2,theta3]`. Then `g(theta) = [g(theta1) g(theta2) g(theta3)]`. Then you `sum`, so you get `f`. Its just literally what the code does, not sure what is there not to understand. I want to help, but I am not sure if you are understanding what I say (I am certainly not understanding what you say)

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
g  = @(x)x.^2
fn = @(varargin)  sum(  cellfun(g,varargin)  )
```

Now we have an anonymous function with a variable number of inputs. Example use below

```
fn(1)           % = 1
fn(1,5,3)       % = 35 = (1^2+5^2+3^2)
fn(1,2,3,4,5,6) % = 91 = (1^2 + 2^2 + 3^2 + 4^2 + 5^2 + 6^2)
```

Comment: While this may be what op is looking for, this is the worse version of never creating `fn` and just doing `g([1,5,3])`. The result is the same, but your version is unnecessarily complicated and slower.

Comment: True for this toy example. However, I understood the original question to be simply "is it possible to make an arbitrary input anonymous function?" I've never tried, and was somewhat surprised to realize that it was. Perhaps there is a use case for this, although o have never found the need myself. This seems similar to Matlab questions that ask how to use programmatically defined variable names. It's usually a bad idea, but there is still an answer. Sometimes there is a weird specific need.

Comment: You can do that also in a better way though. Make a function on another file that takes `varargin` and then do `fn=@myfun;`.  That way you can also parse inputs. This is the worst of both worlds.